# Add delay between array of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm having troubles by adding a delay between executing a Promise. I want them to execute in a specific sequence. I've tried `Promise.mapSeries` without success.

My **working** code currently looks like:

```
await Promise.delay(1000);
await accept(user.id, admin.id);
await Promise.delay(1000);
await accept(user.id, employee.id);
await Promise.delay(1000);
await reject(user.id, employee.id);
```

I've tried this with `Promise.mapSeries` without success:

```
const promises = [
  accept(user.id, admin.id),
  accept(user.id, employee.id),
  reject(user.id, employee.id)
];

await Promise.mapSeries(promises, () => Promise.delay(1000));
```

Comment: `await` is not exactly ES6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mapSeries` doesn't help when you already have an array of promises. Constructing the array and creating the promises already starts the actions, which will run in parallel not in sequence.

The simplest solution would be a simple loop:

```
const actions = [
    { action: accept, target: user, source: admin },
    { action: accept, target: user, source: employee },
    { action: reject, target: user, source: employee }
]
for (const a of actions) {
    await Promise.delay(1000);
    await a.action(a.target.id, a.source.id);
}
```

but you can also use `mapSeries` instead of that:

```
await Promise.mapSeries(actions, a =>
    Promise.delay(1000)
    .then(() => a.action(a.target.id, a.source.id))
);
```

---

If your actions are more heterogenous, just make them functions:

```
const actions = [
    () => accept(user.id, admin.id),
    () => accept(user.id, employee.id),
    () => reject(user.id, employee.id)
];
for (const f of actions) {
    await Promise.delay(1000);
    await f()
}
await Promise.mapSeries(actions, async f => {
    await Promise.delay(1000);
    return f();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the Promises in sequence, you need to delay their execution. You can do this by making your array return a function which then returns a Promise and passing that to `mapSeries`:

```js
const arr = [
    () => Promise.resolve(1) /* () => accept(user.id, admin.id) */,
    () => Promise.resolve(2) /* () => accept(user.id, employee.id) */,
    () => Promise.resolve(3) /* () => reject(user.id, employee.id) */
];
// Now use mapSeries to execute the promises in sequence
Promise.mapSeries(arr, item => {
 return Promise.delay(1000).then(item);
})
.then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.1/bluebird.js"></script>
```